# kerberos setup with freeipa installation

Tags: kerberos, freeipa

I tried installing freeipa on ubuntu v16 (cloud server) using the following:

1. modified /etc/host to use the private IP address of the virtual machine and the corresponding host (the A name has propagated)
2. ran the freeipa-server installation:

   sudo apt-get intall freeipa-server

I added the host information etc. in the responses.  After the installation, I ran the following:

```
kinit admin
```

However, I get the following error:

```
 Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'CORRECT.HOST.COM' while getting initial credentials
```

I checked the realm setup in /etc/krb5.conf file and I can see the host specified there:

```
default_realm = CORRECT.HOST.COM

[realms]
    CORRECT.HOST.COM = {
        kdc = CORRECT.HOST.COM:88
        admin_server = CORRECT.HOST.COM
    }
```

I tried modifying the host name to lowercase (as well as the port number).  However, the kinit command does not work.

```
KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stdout kinit admin
[30263] 1524933806.532808: Getting initial credentials for admin@CORRECT.HOST.COM
[30263] 1524933806.536715: Sending request (185 bytes) to CORRECT.HOST.COM
[30263] 1524933806.537110: Resolving hostname correct.host.com
[30263] 1524933806.537618: Sending initial UDP request to dgram 10.132.61.210:88
[30263] 1524933806.537806: Initiating TCP connection to stream 10.132.61.210:88
[30263] 1524933806.537942: Terminating TCP connection to stream 10.132.61.210:88
kinit: Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'CORRECT.HOST.COM' while getting initial credentials
```

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this further (preferably installing on an ubuntu v16 server and not fedora)

Comment: Is that the correct IP address? Did you actually start the FreeIPA server? What is its status? And why on earth do you want to use Ubuntu for this?!

Comment: hi Michael - I realize it would be more convenient to run on fedora/red hat but all the other servers we're using are running ubuntu and I wanted to have the same infrastructure in place (instead of relying on different tools for just this VM)  - if not possible, I'll go with fedora.  I cannot run kinit correctly (connection to KDC is not established) - I am running this command right after ipa-server install command.  The hostname/A name is correct and is set via an external DNS provider.

Comment: I tried starting via systemctl but got the error (  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-04-28 22:59:19 UTC; 14s ago
  Process: 1414 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ipactl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
)

Comment: I tried using both the private and public ip addresses in the /etc/hosts file but without success

Comment: FreeIPA is developed on, and runs best on, Fedora and RHEL/CentOS. It's also well documented for these platforms. I've heard other unrelated complaints about the Debian/Ubuntu FreeIPA ports, and I always recommend running it on one of the above distros.

Comment: What messages are logged in the journal or in FreeIPA's logs when you tried to start it?

Comment: for kerberos:  systemctl start krb5kdc
Failed to start krb5kdc.service: Unit krb5kdc.service not found.

Comment: i only see server and client install logs for ipa in /var/log

Comment: Is it already solved?

Comment: i ended up using fedora - the installation worked out of the box on that OS but never on ubuntu correctly without issues